# How to pass null for a parameter in stored procedure - the parameter is uniqueidentifier

Tags: nullable

In C# code I have a variable Guid? name.But,how to initialize this parameter to null,since I cannot assign null for a guid type

Answer (score 1):

Set the parameter value to `DBNull.Value`.

Answer (score 0):

```
param = New SqlParameter("@GUID_ID", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier, 16)
param.Value = DBNull.Value
```